# Is there a method/way to retrieve text color of a cell value?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to retrieve data from an Excel file with OpenXML with C#, and display them in a dataGridView.

I retrieve all the values I need, but I have to retrieve the text color of this values too to be able to display them as they are in the file.

I looked in different threads how to change the color of the text, and tried to use the same way, but I can't find a way to have all the colors of my data.

I tried to retrieve the Color of the cell, sometimes I have the Rgb value, but most of the cases, I just have a color index, or nothing.

I tried to look in the XML files of the Excel file, but I wasn't able to find a way to link everything

```
private string GetTextColor(Cell cell, Stylesheet stylesheet)
{
        CellFormats cellFormats = stylesheet.CellFormats;
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat cellFormat = cellFormats.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellFormat>().ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(cell.StyleIndex.Value));
        var textColor = stylesheet.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color>().ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(cellFormat.FillId.Value));
        return textColor.Rgb; //Null most of the case
}
```

I don't know if there is another way to obtain the color of the text, I tried a lot of methods but I can't find one ...

Thanks in advance for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way to do it :

I found that color can be found in 2 ways : Directly from a RGB hexadecimal code, or in the ColorScheme depending if the color used is defined in the theme.

So first, I iterate through TableCellProperties of the cell like this :

```
foreach(D.TableCellProperties cPr in _cell.Elements<D.TableCellProperties>())
```

and then I iterate through SolidFill too :

```
foreach(D.SolidFill sldFill in cPr.Elements<D.SolidFill>())
```

(Where D is defined as `using D = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;`)

After this, I'm able to detect if SchemeColor or RgbColorHexModel isn't null.

First case :
If the value `sldFill.ShemeColor` is not null, I will retrieve all the colors contained in the color scheme of the file :

```
presentationDocument.PresentationPart.ThemePart.Theme.ThemeElements.ColorScheme;
```

And, I'll iterate until I found the same color name. After this, I'm able to retrieve the RGB value with this paramater :

```
//colorName represent the color found in the ColorScheme
colorName.Elements<D.RgbColorModelHex>()
```

Second case :
If the value `sldFill.RgbColorModelHex` is not null, I just retrieve the hex code like this :

```
color = sldFill.RgbColorModelHex.Val;
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past:

```
int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Range) cell.Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer, this is what I did, but this way is used with the Interop library, but it doesn't work with OpenXML (I want to use OpenXML because it's faster than Interop).
The problem is, I cannot have every color text when I try, sometimes I have the rgb property, but sometimes it's empty even if the color is different from the previous cell ...